# Automatic variable broken with PowerShell 4

Tags: variables, powershell

Using PowerShell 2, I can correctly use the `$$` variable

```
PS > $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
2

PS > Convert-Path 'Program Files'
C:\Program Files

PS > Convert-Path $$
C:\Program Files
```

However with PowerShell 4 the same command produces an error

```
PS > $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
4

PS > Convert-Path 'Program Files'
C:\Program Files

PS > Convert-Path $$
Convert-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\'Program Files'' because it does not exist.
```

How can I use this example with PowerShell 4?

[about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Invoke-Expression` to expand the string.

```
PS > Convert-Path 'Program Files'
C:\Program Files

PS > Convert-Path (Invoke-Expression $$)
C:\Program Files
```

Using aliases:

```
PS > cvpa (iex $$)
C:\Program Files
```

You could even use this to create an automatic variable of your own. Here, I use `4` since it's on the same key as `$`.

Put this in your Profile:

```
$Global:4 = 0
$null = Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable 4 -Action {
        $global:4 = Invoke-Expression $$} -Mode Read
```

Then you can run:

```
PS > Convert-Path 'Program Files'
C:\Program Files

PS > Convert-Path $4
C:\Program Files
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
Convert-Path 'Program Files'

Convert-Path ($$ -replace "`'", '')
```

edit after comment:

```
 Convert-Path ($$ -replace "^`'|`'$", '')
```

to replace only single quote at the start and at the end of the $$

Comment: Try and see,  I cannot test it now

Comment: If the path was `ProgramFiles'` this will fail.